# How to manipulate attachement path on DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.TextEditor

Tags: dotnetnuke

Im kinda new to DNN and I need to control the text editor not to show the system files when users attach files to a mini blog. Is there a way to manipulate the DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.TextEditor attachment path to look only on a specified folder and not defaulting to ~/portal/[portalid]?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Host/ HTML Configuration Manager page you can choose the "Path" that the Text Editor loads by default (found under the Image Manager Settings section)

You can also make those settings apply only to a specific page or role if necessary

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll look into this and see how stuff works under this hood.